# What is the momentum mapping for a left translation group action?

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics, symplectic-geometry, moment-map

In this survey of [Symplectic Geometry](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/arnogive.pdf) by Arnol'd and Givental in 1985, an example of momentum mappings was given on Page 62 as follows:

> The action of the group by left translations on its cotangent bundle is Poisson. The corresponding momentum mapping $P:T^*G \to \mathfrak{g}^*$ coincides with the right translation of covectors to the identity element of the group.

I want to understand this example in a simple and concrete setting. So let's take $G = \mathbb{R}$. Then $T^*G \cong \mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathfrak{g}^* \cong \mathbb{R}$, and the identity element of the group $\mathbb{R}$ is zero. The physical meaning of this example is a particle moving on the real line with coordinate $q$ at a momentum $p$.

**How does the momentum mapping $P: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ coincide with the right translation of covectors to zero?**

So I'm asking what exactly the map $P$ is and what Arnol'd and Givental meant by "the right translation of covectors to zero".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your identifications, the mapping would be simply $P(q,p) = p$. Or if you wanted to think of $\mathfrak{g}^*$ as being $T^*_0G$ (the cotangent space at $0\in\mathbb{R}$), it would be $P(q,p) = (0,p)$, i.e. the momentum at $q\in\mathbb{R}$, but translated to the identity $0\in\mathbb{R}$. If your Hamiltonian is translation-invariant, this will be conserved under the Hamiltonian flow.

Also, right translation of a covector to zero would be the map $(q,p)\mapsto (0,p)$. (This is also left translation of a covector to zero - left and right translation agree since the underlying group is Abelian.)

Comment: This makes perfect sense. So what Arnold and Givental said was "the map $(q,p) \mapsto p$ coincides with $(q,p) \mapsto (0,p)$". Somehow the phrase "the right translation of covectors to zero" sounds more like $(q,p) \mapsto (q,0)$ to me.

Comment: Right translation here just means that $q\mapsto q+(-q)=0$, vs left translation meaning $q\mapsto (-q)+q=0$. They agree since addition is commutative. The cotangent lift of this action is $(q,p)\mapsto (0,p)$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My gap in the understanding of this "trivial" example is probably due to a lack of a proper "translation" (left or right) of the physics language to the math language.